# Django REST - Custom Serializer for Full Username

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I have an application with Django/Django-REST on the backend with Angular on the front-end. I am looking for the correct way to convert a user ID to a full username for display in an Angular JS modal.

Here is my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ArtnetTasks
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_assigned = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d')
    assigned_by_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('full_username')
    assigned_to_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('full_username')

    def full_username(self, id):

        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
        name = user.first_name + " " + user.last_name
        return name

    class Meta:
        model = ArtnetTasks, Users
        fields = ('id', 'headline', 'message', 'assigned_to', 'assigned_to_name', 'assigned_by', 'assigned_by_name', 'date_assigned', )
```

My Model:

```
class ArtnetTasks(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=75L)
    message = models.TextField()
    response_message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    assigned_to = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    assigned_by = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_assigned = models.DateTimeField()
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'artnet_tasks'
```

assigned_to and assigned_by are user_id's that correspond with auth_user

It is throwing the following error then promptly breaking the Angular AJAX calls, the error from what I can tell is "argument must be a string or a number\054 not 'dict'"

This is my first project using both Django-REST and Angular and am sure I am missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you can not set more than one model on your serializer. Your serializer can only handle one model per time. Another thing, the **SerializerMethodField** has as parameter **self** and **obj**, where, **obj** is your **ArtnetTasks** instance. As a better RESTful practice, I recommend you the follow example, if your user is authenticated:

```python
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_assigned = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d')
    assigned_by_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_full_name')
    assigned_to_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_full_name')

    def get_user_full_name(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        user = request.user
        name = user.first_name + " " + user.last_name
        return name

    class Meta:
        model = ArtnetTasks
        fields = ('id', 'headline', 'message', 'assigned_to', 'assigned_to_name',      'assigned_by', 'assigned_by_name', 'date_assigned', )
```

Better than this, I recommend you to create a simple serializer to the User model, and then , instead to use **assigned_by_name** and **assigned_to_name**, you can use:

```python
 user = YourUserSerialuzer()
```

But you will need a relation between **User** and **ArtnetTasks** model to do that.
You can see more examples of how do this, here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations